# Is the StandardScaler important when using the logistic regression as a classifier?

Tags: regression, logistic, python, roc, feature-scaling

I'm training my LR right now and using Brier Score and ROC AUC as my evaluation. In my x_train are binary variables, ordinal variables and numerical variables with a wide range (e.g. 20000 - 160000). After using this code:

scaler = StandardScaler()

x_train_standardized = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)

x_test_standardized = scaler.transform(x_test)

my ROC AUC went from 0.3893707287508621 to 0.8025664068214592.

This shouldn't be, right?

Should I only use the Scaler on my numerical variables or should I use it at all?
I'm happy for every answer :)
Cheers